# Self-service site creation (e.g. MySites) - specify Content DB

Tags: mysites

If I have a web application which shares site collections with - for example - MySites, and other site collections (created with their specified content DB's) is it possible to control which content DB's the MySite Site Collections use? As they are created automatically, it makes it a bit hard to specify explicitly the content DB.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your mysite site collections are in the same web application as your other site collections, they will share content databases. Unfortunately there is no way in specifying which site collections go into which content databases.

This is one of the reasons people like to put mysites in a separate webapp. Nowadays, with the rise of "host named site collections" and them being actually usable now, that idea has perhaps lost some followers but it's still a valid approach.

If multiple content databases are assigned to a web app, a round robin mechanism will be used when creating sites. The only thing you can control here is specifying some content databases not to be used anymore (by setting the maximum number of sites), but that will be true no matter what site collection you create.

The "self service site creation" property is scoped at the webapp level, so you also can't do this at the individual content databases.

Comment: Thanks - yes that was my line of thinking - host named site collections. The round robin is not ideal as some my sites could end up in other sites content Dbs. Looks like MySites still needs to be in its own web application. :)

Comment: Self service site creation does not work with host named site collections. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx#section1f